# Recurrence Relation tree method

Tags: recurrence

I am currently having issues with figuring our some recurrence stuff and since I have midterms about it coming up soon I could really use some help and maybe an explanation on how it works.

So I basically have pseudocode for solving the Tower of Hanoi

```
TOWER_OF_HANOI ( n, FirstRod, SecondRod, ThirdRod)
    if n == 1 
          move disk from FirstRod to ThirdRod 
     else
             TOWER_OF_HANOI(n-1, FirstRod, ThirdRod, SecondRod)
              move disk from FirstRod to ThirdRod
              TOWER_OF_HANOI(n-1, SecondRod, FirstRod, ThirdRod)
```

And provided I understand how to write the relation (which, honestly I'm not sure I do...) it should be T(n) = 2T(n-1)+Ɵ(n), right? I sort of understand how to make a tree with fractional subproblems, but even then I don't fully understand the process that would give you the end solution of Ɵ(n) or Ɵ(n log n) or whatnot.

Thanks for any help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assume the time complexity is T(n), it is supposed to be: T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-1) + 1 = 2T(n-1) + 1. Why "+1" but not "+n"? Since "move disk from FirstRod to ThirdRod" costs you only one move.
2. For T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1, its recursion tree will exactly look like this: 
   https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-complexity-of-T-n-2T-n-1-+-C  (You might find it helpful, the image is neat.) C is a constant; it means the cost per operation. In the case of Tower of Hanoi, C = 1.
3. Calculate the sum of the cost each level, you will easily find out in this case, the total cost will be 2^n-1, which is exponential(expensive). Therefore, the answer of this recursion equation is Ɵ(2^n).